# laser_scan_matcher run problems

Tags: ros, rosbag, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I installed and downloaded successfully the scan_tools stack . Than tried to run the demo example. Have done rosmake rviz rosbag tf without any error. Than when I tried to run de demo by roslaunch laser_scan_matcher demo.launch
I got the following error.

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rosbag/rosbag]: can't locate node [rosbag] in package [rosbag]

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39431/laser_scan_matcher-run-problems/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-07-21

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-21**:
What ROS distribution are you using? What operating system?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-21**:
Im using fuerte and Ubununtu.10.4. Any help?

**Comment by [oleo80](https://answers.ros.org/users/2184/oleo80/) on 2012-07-26**:
Same problem with ar_pose!
The launch file has the same format as in rosbag tutorials. Does something have changed in rosbag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same error using a launch like:

```
<node pkg ="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag" args="play -l $(find package)/data/file.bag"/>
```

And it seems now it works as:

```
<node pkg ="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-l $(find package)/data/file.bag"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) with karma: 738 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-02**:
Right. The reason is that the rosbag binary is installed in /opt/ros/fuerte/bin as of Fuerte while rosrun and roslaunch only consider binaries in /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rosbag. I'm not sure if this behavior was intended but I at least cannot find it documented anywhere. Consider filing a ticket.

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2014-03-24**:
I got the same problem in amcl test. this solution solved the problem :)
I'm using  ubuntu 12.4 LTS & Fuerte.